WORDPRESS HELP: An error is being displayed when I select Reading - Post - Select - to display blog posts
This is the error, I am getting: Warning: these pages should not be the same as your Privacy Policy page!
I tried searching online to see if there was a fix but I couldn't find any. It seems that there is a conflict in page template but I can't seem to pinpoint it.
This theme was developed by another person so I am trying to see if it can be fixed without breaking it. Here is a screenshot of the error
I checked the code to see if I could pinpoint something in the functions.php file but I couldn't see anything ordinary. I also installed a plugin (yes, that sounds shallow) to overcome the issue, WP Blog Designer, but that didn't help either. All plugins state that I have to choose -Select- to display the Posts.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You will find the discussion here interesting, because it is very relevant to your question: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46831
Let's see the gist of it. Someone requested that a warning with the exact same text as your warning should be displayed:

It would be nice if a similar warning would indicate if the Privacy Policy page was accidentally set as either. Maybe a message along the lines of; "Warning: these pages should not be the same as your Privacy Policy page!"

So it seems that you have set your privacy policy page as your homepage, or something like that.

And here's the diff: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/46831/46831.2.diff
So this is only a warning, not an error, but it was added for a reason and maybe it's a good idea to heed the warning.
